# CentOS : Dependency Resolution Errors

Tags: centos, updates, dependencies, software-update

I had been using Ubuntu for quite sometime and recently installed CentOS and getting the below error when I update using yum. How do I resolve such errors?

```
Dependency Resolution Errors:
Package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.19-3.el6.rf.x86_64 (@rpmforge)  
    Requires: libmodplug.so.0()(64bit)  
    Removing: libmodplug-0.8.7-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (@rpmforge)  
        libmodplug.so.0()(64bit)  
    Updated By: 1:libmodplug-0.8.8.3-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)  
        Not found
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've run CentOS, so my memory's fuzzy, but it looks to me like there are a couple of possible problems:

First, it looks like you're using both EPEL and RPMforge (now known as Repoforge).  I don't think that those two repos are guaranteed to work together; you might want to try disabling EPEL to see if your problem goes away.  ([This question](https://serverfault.com/q/209046/8437) discusses EPEL versus RPMforge in more detail.)

Second, the "not found" error while trying to install the EPEL version of libmodplug makes it sound like there might be a problem with your EPEL config or your access to EPEL repositories.  I'm not sure.